# How to fulfill the Mitzvah of bikkur hollim for someone that's contagious?

Tags: mitzvah, choleh-sick

A close friend recently got infected with shingles, a contagious disease. I would like to fulfill the Mitzvah of bikkur hollim (visiting the sick) but do not want to jeapordize my health in the process.

What sort of options do I have of doing the Mitzvah without causing self-harm?

Comment: Sending cards, telephone call, video chat, etc. No sources, so not posting as an answer.

Comment: As always, CYLOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Star-K [Website](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-HalachicGuidetoHospitals.htm):

> Although it is preferable to visit someone in person, if one is unable to do so or if the patient prefers, one may fulfill the mitzvah of bikur cholim by telephoning (or emailing) the patient

The footnote is a bit off (the number is 39, but the link codes it to #38) but the source is one of these 2:

38. Gesher Hachaim pg 212.
39. Igros Moshe Y.D. 1:223.

Comment: If emailing fulfills the mitzvah, try Skype or similar!